# Why every characters I typed will appear on standard output immediately?

Tags: operating-system

I am reviewing the operating system these days and have a questions right now. Suppose I am running a C++ program and there is a `std::cin>>i;` line at the very begining of the program, the program(process) should only have one thread and try to read from the user buffer of cin, which is empty right now. The user buffer should try to read from kernel buffer, which is also empty right now because there is not any cache created by I/O operations before.

The operaing system should put the thread into sleep and wait for the keyboard device to send an interrupt. When I type something such as '123' on my keyboard, they directly appear in the terminal, Why? Does this mean '123' is stored in the standard output file?

Another question is everytime I press keyboard, an interrupt should be generated. The pressed character will be put into the kernel buffer. Since there is no data in the user buffer yet, the thread is still sleep. Only when I press the 'enter', all data in kernel buffer will be flushed into the user buffer and the thread wakes up and keep running. Is my understanding right?

Comment: What does "operating system" mean in "I am reviewing the operating system these days"?

Comment: The characters you type appear *in the terminal window*, which isn't quite the same thing as your program's `stdout` (which also appears in the terminal window).

Comment: I am reviewing the operating system course knowledge these days @tadman.

Comment: All of the particulars depend on your operating system, and your terminal.  None of the particulars depend on C++.

Comment: You may be confusing the purpose of a terminal, which is to capture input and display output, with a program's input and output *streams* via STDIN and STDOUT + STDERR respectively. The interaction between these two is largely up to the OS and/or the terminal used, but there are strong conventions in the UNIX/POSIX world.

Comment: In this context "operating system" is exceedingly vague to the point of being meaningless. DOS is an "operating system" according to some definitions but it handles this quite differently. If you mean "POSIX-type" then we can talk in terms of specifics, as that standard does have a lot of concrete examples and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function built into the kernel - specifically, into the terminal driver. It is available for serial ports (`/dev/ttyS<n>` files), virtual terminals (`/dev/tty<n>`) and pseudo-terminals (`/dev/pts/<n>`).

This functionality is tied specifically to those files - it is **not** tied to standard input or output. If stdin/stdout is redirected into a file or pipe - those functions would not be available. On the other hand, if you manually open one of those files - this functionality will appear.

By default, several modifications are done to the input:

- the input is buffered until `Enter` is pressed
- echo is enabled - all input is immediately copied to the output, bypassing the program
- line editing is enabled - `Backspace`, `Delete`, and arrow keys are interpreted as editing commands. They modify the content of the buffer.
- some control characters (`Crtl-C`, `Ctrl-Z`, etc) are converted into signals.

It is possible to disable some or all of those:

- if buffering is disabled, all typed characters will be immediately passed to the program. `Backspace` will be a character, `Delete` and arrow keys will produce escape sequences.
- if control characters are disabled - `Ctrl+<character>` will produce ASCII codes instead of signals.
- if echo is disabled - typed characters will not appear on the screen. This is the setting that `sudo` uses, when it asks for your password.

The settings can be modified by `ioctl` system call. There is a library called "termios", that provides C wrappers for those options. There is also shell command: `stty` - that allows to modify those settings from the command line. Note, that those settings may persist between programs! You have to restore them, when your program is done! `reset` command restores the default terminal settings.